# Average length of table column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 50+  VARCHAR(255) columns.
The moderators report that some of the content is cut of after 250 characters in few of the fields.

As checked this is expected behavior for `VARCHAR(255)` and I have to update some of the fields to `text`. But the problem is they can not give me details/instruction which fields are making problems ..

So my best guess is to analyse the current data and find the columns that usually store long content.

Is there a good query structure I can use to get:
 - AVG length for each column.
 - Max length for each column.
 - Count of rows with  length 200+ for this column.

Comment: What about `AVG`, `MAX`, and `COUNT`, combined with `WHERE` and `CHAR_LENGTH`?

Comment: Yes, but how to combine them nicely? I can run 20+10 queries and log the data .. but there should be a better approach.

Comment: 50+ columns is sometimes indicative of poor (i.e. non-normalised) design.

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT AVG(CHAR_LENGTH(col)) avg_length,
       MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(col)) max_length,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(col) >= 200 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 200_plus_count
  FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Use the [information_schema.columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) table to build the queries.

Comment: @d.raev What VMai said, you'll probably have to run each query separately.

Answer (score 1):

For average select AVG(length(column_name)) and for maximum select MAX(length(column_name)) for count 200+ select COUNT(column_name) from table WHERE len(rows)=>200.  This site should help you with other sql related questions, hope I answered your question :)

Comment: thanks for  the help @londani, the goal is to combine all this in one massive query for all the columns:)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had reason to implement exactly this. Using similar logic as Arth's and VMai's answers, I built a stored procedure to get all column sizes for a table.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ColumnSizeForTable(TableName varchar(64), SchemaName varchar(64))
BEGIN
SELECT @@group_concat_max_len INTO @group_concat_max;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000;
SELECT 
    CONCAT('SELECT TRIM(TRAILING \' UNION ALL \' FROM CAST(CONCAT(',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                CONCAT('\'SELECT \\\'', COLUMN_NAME, '\\\' ColName,\''),
                ', ',
                CONCAT('IFNULL(AVG(CHAR_LENGTH(',COLUMN_NAME,')),\'0\'), \' ColAverage,\''),
                ', ',
                CONCAT('IFNULL(MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(',COLUMN_NAME,')),\'0\'), \' ColMaximum,\''),
                ', ',
                CONCAT('IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(',COLUMN_NAME,') >= 200 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),\'0\'), \' Col200Plus UNION ALL \'')
            )
        ),
        ') AS CHAR)) INTO @unionquery FROM ',
        TABLE_NAME,
        ';')
INTO @columnquery FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = TableName
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = SchemaName
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;

PREPARE columnsizestmnt FROM @columnquery;
EXECUTE columnsizestmnt;
PREPARE unionstmnt FROM @unionquery;
EXECUTE unionstmnt;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @group_concat_max;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL ColumnSizeForTable('TABLENAME','SCHEMANAME');
```

How this works:

1. Increase the session variable group_concat_max_len so we don't have to worry about GROUP_CONCAT being cut off.
2. Execute a concat query that builds *another* query.

   - This first query populates the column names.
   - The resulting query is put into @columnquery
3. Execute @columnquery. This builds the query to put the data into a readable format

   - This second query gets the column data, including average, max, and the 200+ count.
   - Similar to VMai's answer, if we weren't building another query from this, it would be a flattened result set.
   - The resulting query is put into @unionquery
4. Execute @unionquery. This SELECT is outputted to the user. It returns the column details that we were trying to collect in a single, readable format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building on Arths good answer and integrating my comment. This query should **build the query to be executed**:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        -- The `SELECT` keyword
        'SELECT ',
        -- we build our list of analyzing columns with a GROUP_CONCAT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT (
        -- of the columns from Arths answer
        CONCAT ('AVG(CHAR_LENGTH(', COLUMN_NAME, ')) AVG_', COLUMN_NAME), ', ', 
        CONCAT ('MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(', COLUMN_NAME, ')) MAX_', COLUMN_NAME), ', ', 
        CONCAT ('COUNT((CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(', COLUMN_NAME, ') >= 200 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 200_plus_', COLUMN_NAME)      
    ), ' '),
    -- and add the FROM clause
    ' FROM ',
    TABLE_NAME,
    ';' )

FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    -- replace it by your own
    TABLE_NAME = 'example10'
GROUP BY
    TABLE_NAME;
```

**Note**

It's not nicely formatted, but a search by `,` and replace by `,\n` with an editor like notepad++ will make the statement readable. So you'll missing the annoying task of writing this by hand and not making mistakes.

Comment: Thanks I did something similar with PHP, there are many ways to concatinate a huge query, I was more interested in **pure SQL** tools to do this .. in elegant way.